# Transit visa requirement at Dammam (DMM)

Tags: transit-visas, saudi-arabia

I booked my tickets from Frankfurt to New Delhi. My itinerary happens to go through Dammam (DMM). When I visit Kiwi (where I booked my ticket), it says that I might require a transit visa.

Here's my itinerary (different carriers):

```
SAW to DMM (arrival 1:10 AM Jul 26) Pegasus
DMM to DEL (departure 5:00 AM Jul 26) IndiGo Airlines
```

Will I require a transit visa?

Comment: Which airline is DMM-DEL? I can't see any airline that sells anything like that itinerary on a single PNR.

Comment: My bad, I read it wrong somehow- you're right, the PNRs are different.

Comment: What is your citizenship?

Answer (score 3):

Saudi Arabia generally allows "Transit Without Visa" (TWOV) at Dammam - presuming your itinerary allows you to stay within the international transit area of the airport.  Unfortunately in your case this is almost certainly not possible.

Pegasus do not allowed transfer of baggage to another airline when connecting on a separate PNR/ticket.  This means that on arrival in Dammam you will need to clear immigration to collect your bags, and then check-in for your connecting flight on IngiGo.

As you will need to clear immigration, you will require a visa.

The only exception to this would be if you were not checking bags, in which case you should be able to stay within the international transit area, and would not require a visa.  However even then there is a risk that Pegasus would not allow you to board given that your connecting flight is on a separate ticket. This risk is likely low, but there are plenty of horror stories out there when it comes to Pegasus...

Comment: The end of the answer is most relevant - it's quite likely that Pegasus would not board a passenger without a visa to Saudi Arabia. As far as they're concerned you're not connecting so TWOV is irrelevant.

Comment: @ugoren Most airlines will allowing boarding in a situation like this as long as you can show proof of the 'connecting' flight (for the no checked bags case). That said, Pegasus does not necessarily fit into my 'most airlines' category, so it's definitely a risk.

Comment: I am not checking in any baggage, and luckily I can also get my boarding ticket for the connecting flight online. I called Pegasus, and they said if DMM has TWOV, they have no reason to not allow me boarding in FRA. I have reached out to the embassy, but still waiting for a response.